# java.security.AccessControlException How can Get full rights?

Tags: java

Totally new to java and and struggling.
I need to get the user preferred language
I did the following
 Locale userPreferredLocale = Locale.getDefault() ;
However the above despite my Language being "da-DK" it always gets "en-GB"

so I tried the the following which I think will return the correct user language
String locale = System.getProperty("user.language");
System.out.println("The Locale of the system is: "+locale);

However now I crash with
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.language read)
What do I need to do so that I have full rights?
Do I need to create a file and put it somewhere ?

Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Is this a standalone Java application, an applet or a web started app?

Comment: Hi,it's a asp.net application with a javaapplet on page

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but what happens when you specifically run the program as root or administrator?
Sometimes it isn't your code what causes the problem...

Comment: I am running as an Administrator

Comment: I have added the following to the Java.Policy but still get the same error 
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "user.language", "read, write"

ANy suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

rebooted the system and not sure makes sense but now It seems ok